# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1}\right|$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate: $$\lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1}\right|$$

My attempt :
$\lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1}\right|$ 
$$ = \lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{x^2+x-1}{x-1}\right|$$

I'm a bit stuck. My first thought was that the limit does not exist because without the absolute value, it tends to negative infinity from the left and positive infinity from the right. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the absolute value.

Comment: the function tends to $\infty$

Comment: Well, direct substitution yields $1/0$, so this won't have a finite value.  If a thing approaches $-\infty$ as $x \to 1^-$, what does the absolute value of that thing approach as $x \to 1^-$?

Comment: Is it : $$\lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{-x^2-x+2}{x-1}\right|$$ ?

Comment: @JaideepKhare no it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x \to 1$ ;
$$ \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1} = \frac{\to (-1)}{\to 0} \longrightarrow \pm \infty$$

Hence :

$$\left| \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1}\right| \longrightarrow +\infty$$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \left| \frac{-x^2-x+1}{x-1}\right|$ Diverges, ane therefore, it **Does Not Exist**